# How to avoid overlaps when executing at x intervals per second?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code that writes to a socket every *x*ms per second (so for example writes to a socket every 100 milliseconds) and outputs the response to the console.

The problem is when the result gets written to the Console there are sometimes duplicate timings, meaning two socket sends are being sent at the exact same tick so to speak. The code for this is shown below. (The connection between the client and server is consistently less than half a millisecond).

Edit: Stupidly forgot to mention this is multi threaded software that has 4 threads running the same logic below.

```
// Edit: Eurgh I typed this out stupidly. These belong to the class not method.
var milliseconds = 100; // How long to sleep between each socket write.
var lastSendTime = 0; 

//....setup socket etc....
while(true)
{
    // Keep waiting until were ready..
    while(((DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / 10000) - (lastSendTime)) < milliseconds)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1); // Await so as not to affect performance
    }

    lastSendTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / 10000;

    // .. socket send and receive..
    Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / 10000 + "]" + ":" + response);
}
```

So of course an example of duplicate output would be as follows (note the first two lines):

```
[63529897318427]:response
[63529897318427]:response
[63529897318527]:response
[63529897318627]:response
```

So how come this is happening sometimes and how can I prevent it?

Comment: You know DateTime is only accurate to about 15ms. Also you should not rely on a hardcoded 10000 Ticks per millisecond, you should use `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks/TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond` instead.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: it is accurate to 3ms not 15 ;) values will always be dividable by 3.

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou no, it is as accurate as your "Current Timer Interval" as reported by [ClockRes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897568) (which by default is 15 ms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is what is know as a [Critical Section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section). You can use a `Mutex` to make sure the code is only executed one at a time. Have a look at [Mutex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And here is a very good example how to use it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx#vcwlkthreadingtutorialexample4mutex

Comment: Thanks for the tip totally forgot about Mutex! This is most likely what I need but I will come back to accept your answer in a bit if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your wait loop to wait once the needed time instead of sitting inside a semi-tight loop

```
// ..setup socket etc...
var milliseconds = 100; // How long to sleep between each socket write.
var lastSendTime = 0; 

while(true)
{
    var remainingMilliseconds = milliseconds - ((DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond) - lastSendTime);

    await Task.Delay(Math.Max(0, remainingMilliseconds));
    lastSendTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

    // .. socket send and receive..
    Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond + "]" + ":" + response);
}
```

However using DateTime.UtcNow will only be as accurate as your "Current timer interval" as reported by [ClockRes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897568) (by default it is 15ms but higher end hardware can have the option to lower it). Using `Stopwatch` instead of `DateTime` it will use the reported "Minimum Timer Interval" as the resolution instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you unite the four threads into one - there's no point in having four threads all waiting for something to happen, and each of them doing something every once in a while. If you unite them into one thread, you'll avoid all overlaps and all locking issues.

Comment: Agreed, then you just stop the timer whilst doing the work and restart it when done, problem solved!

Comment: The actual software I've written requires 4 open connections to the socket server. I can't elaborate as to why but I can't unite them.

Comment: Don't unite the connections, just the thread that sends data at specific times.

Comment: Care to elaborate with some example code please? So do you mean one thread that rotates the connections?

Comment: Well, actually, yes, is there a reason to keep one thread per connection anyway?

Comment: Without going into too much detail, think of it as my software racing against others to be the first to send certain data to the server, hence 4 connections (the maximum allowed by the server) simply improves the chances of being first in. :)

Comment: Five years later I've seen this comment. No, 4 connections to not improve your chances, unless you have four different network cards going through four different ISPs.